# Regex to to select 3 pages + any sub-pages

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I need a regex for a google goal that pulls in only 3 pages and their child pages

The pages are:

https://test.com/employers/
https://test.com/employers/any-page-in-employers-folder

https://test.com/partners/
https://test.com/partners/any-page-in-partners-folder

https://test.com/brokers/
https://test.com/brokers/any-page-in-brokers-folder

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In Analytics you can generically use this:

```
\/employers\/|\/partners\/|\/brokers\/
```

If you want it to be more robust and you don't have the domain in the reports you can use this:

```
^\/employers\/|^\/partners\/|^\/brokers\/
```

If you also have the domain and the protocol you can use this:

```
https:\/\/test\.com(\/employers\/|\/partners\/|\/brokers\/)
```